# In terms of an object what is an invoice and a users cash balance?

Tags: oop

Both an invoice and an users balance can have money added to it?

The invoice has an upper limit of the invoice's price and when filled the invoice is considered paid.

If we had an abstract object be the parent of both the users balance and an invoice what would the abstract object be?

The concrete issue is that I have payments and I have to associate the payments  and allocate amounts to either the users balances or invoices.

I thought about Payable, but how do you pay to a balance?

```
payment->attach(invoice);
payment->attach(userBalance);

//payment object 
function attach(WhatInterface whatInterface) {
    this->whatInterfaces->add(whatInterface); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with object-oriented design is that really there's no answer to your question. Lions, tigers and pussies are all "cats", which are all "animals", but software objects seldom show that sort of intuitively graspable natural hierarchy.
A user's balance is presumably an amount of money, and invoice is a demand for an amount of money. Now you could say invoice "isa" amount of money, or you could say invoice "hasa" amount of money, which is the demand, plus other amounts of money (the VAT, the amount paid, subtotals for the various items).

But there's no right or wrong. It depends on your particular program. I'd guess this is a computer science 101 exercise and your tutor is looking for the answer "accounts".

Comment: Nope... production system i'm afraid :( I have considered accounts, but that is way too ambiguous, since the user can register. What do you think about Payable?

Comment: How about call them Monetary? That implies you can add or subtract other Monetaries from it.

Comment: So basically they would have an addMoney on them?

Comment: Yes, probably with a guard to prevent adding negatives (you can't pay -100 dollars on you electricity bill then go to the Bahamas to spend it).